# Does the Splash Radius chip affect the Luna Blaster?

Tags: splatoon-3, splatoon-3-side-order

In Splatoon 3 Side Order, there is a Splash Radius chip which "Increases the radius of damage and turf inked by explosions". I believe this applies to explosions when enemies are defeated, but does it also apply to shots fired by the Luna Blaster?

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't?

Comment: @pinckerman It seemed like something that would count, but I wasn't sure.